# How do I select any value from SP?

Tags: sql

I have SP like :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySP
(
@startdate datetime = null,
@enddate datetime = null
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @date datetime 
Set @date= convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101))
  SET @startdate = ISNULL(@startdate,convert (datetime,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)))
select @startdate -- i want to select and view this value
END
GO
```

I want to view `select @startdate` value, How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You execute the stored procedure.

```
exec MySP
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
2011-08-10 00:00:00.000
```

**Edit**

Stored procedure with output parameter @startdate

```
alter PROCEDURE MySP
(
@startdate datetime = null out,
@enddate datetime = null
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @date datetime 
  Set @date= convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101))
  SET @startdate = ISNULL(@startdate,convert (datetime,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)))
END
```

Use like this

```
declare @D datetime
exec MySP @D out
select @D
```

Comment: Well... you could use @startdate as an output parameter.

Comment: Can you plz elaborate with EXAMPLE :)

Comment: @Ashish - Updated answer. Removed `select @startdate` and added `out` to `@startdate` parameter.